# Encoding problems CSV to XLS with PHPExcel

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel, export-to-excel

I'am saving some form data into a XLS document using PHPExcel library. Firstly, I make a CSV document with the info, and then, I convert CSV data to XLS using that library. The fact is that CSV document has a perfect UTF-8, for example, accent some letters for Spanish text, but when I try to import the info to an XLS document, I lose that encoding. 
I use the next code to implement that:

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('CSV');

$objReader->setDelimiter("|");
$objReader->setInputEncoding('UTF-8');

$url_csv="./archivos_csv/curriculums.csv";
$url_xls="./archivos_xls/curriculums.xls";

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($url_csv);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save($url_xls);
```

Excel5 document doesn't have correct encoding. Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: If the input file is UTF-8 encoded, and because the Excel5 Writer always writes UTF-8, then no conversion of any kind is made by PHPExcel.... which makes this very difficult to understand. Are you absolutely certain that your input file is UTF-8 and not simply extended ASCII? Can you provide a sample to try and help diagnose this problem?

Comment: My input date comes from a form located in a website. CSV data is correct, for example with words like "dirección", but when imports data to XLS, it only receives "direcci".

Comment: Can you provide a sample to try and help diagnose this problem? If I can't recreate a problem, I can't fix it.... I've run tests against various UTF-8 CSV files (with and without BOM) without problems, so there's something in your specific file that is causing this problem.

Comment: What do you need exactly? A sample of my CSV document and another of the generated XLS document? Or do you also need code of the form?

Comment: Basically just the CSV file: I can write a script to do the read/write; but I need a file that I know triggers the problem so that I can do some diagnostics.

Comment: Here it goes: Fecha Recepcion | Nombre | Apellidos | DNI | Direccion | Telefono | Email | Altura | Talla Cuerpo | Talla Pie | Fecha Nacimiento | Dias Disponibles | Tipo de jornada | Permiso de Conducir | Vehiculo Propio | Formacion | Experiencia Laboral | Referencias | Comentarios | Trabajo de Interes | Autoriza a contactar
05/03/2014 | Pepito | Morales | 89843645f | dirección actual | 988776655 | bla@bla.com | Altura | Vestido/Pantalón | Pié | 31/01/2014 | Lunes | Jornada completa | Si | Si | resumen | experiencia |  |  | Personal técnico de la empresa (Periodistas, RRPP...) | Sí

Comment: I actually need a file, not simply the contents copy/pasted into a web application that will manipulate it in various ways for its own presentation (not least the obvious lack of linefeeds).... the PHPExcel codeplex site provides an upload option - https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/workitem/10749

Comment: Done, you can  find the document as "curriculums.csv" in the link you sent me before

Comment: Thanks, I'll Take a look at it over my lunch break

Comment: The file you've sent me isn't UTF-8, though I've not yet identified what charset it actually is... example, the `ó` character in `dirección actual` is a single byte `0xF3`, in UTF-8 it would be a double byte sequence `0xC3 0xB3`, while the `é` in `Pié` is `0xE9` when the UTF-8 value for that character is `0xC3 0xA9`... with these values, the actual charset could be any of ISO 8859-1, 8859-2, 8859-3, 8859-9, 8859-10, 8859-13, 8859-14, 8859-15 or 8859-16

Comment: Oh, then I'm going to force it in UTF8 when I write the file, using PHP function `utf8_encode($data)`. I'll tell you about the results soon.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot telling you about results. It works perfectly now. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Everything good, when you can convert data before load... but how to use encoding when document I receive already in encoding CP1252? Don't want to make duplicate, new file in UTF